Helmholtz decomposition doubt
On the Wiki page for Helmholtz decomposition, it is said that certain differentiable vector fields can be resolved into the sum of an irrotational (curl-free) vector field and a solenoidal (divergence-free) vector field.
And than it is stated as:
$${\displaystyle \mathbf {F} =-\nabla \Phi +\nabla \times \mathbf {A} }$$
I am just starting my fluid dynamics class, but there we defined that we can decompose a velocity vector field as:
$$\mathbf u = \nabla \varphi + \nabla \times \psi\tag2$$
where $\varphi$ is the velocity potential and $\psi$ is the stream function (a kind of vector potential).
Now I am confused on why is there a minus sign in the general definition of the Helmholtz decomposition.
Is it only a matter of convention and, since in fluid dynamics we define a velocity potential positive as $\mathbf u = \nabla \varphi$, we end up with the positive sign and the velocity field defined as it it and also because the Helmholtz decomposition is not unique?
Second question
As I understand, the equation $(2)$ is the general vector field definition. So just to be sure, we can describe all kind of velocity fields possible with that kind of equation? Meaning even with rotation and nonpotential?
Addendum
On the Wiki page for the Stream function under "In terms of vector potential and stream surfaces"
they define a similar function:
$${\displaystyle \mathbf {u} =\nabla \psi \times \nabla \phi \tag3}$$
Is that a typo of the Helmholtz decomposition or are they defining something totally different? Are the two equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ connected somehow?


Yes you do what you want with a sign or even a constant. Just call $\phi=-\Phi$ and you are good to go. 2. I believe you need a differentiable (you are taking derivative) field that vanishes sufficiently fast at infinity (the proof I think requires the existence of fourier transform). These 2 conditions are always verified for physical velocity fields. Except maybe for shock waves. That are in any case a little bit pathological


@Syrocco yes, Helmholtz decomposition as written on even the Wiki page requires that the field decay fast enough at infinity. There is a section on that in the Wiki page. In practice, it is easier to just extract the simple behaviour at infinity out for explicit handling.

Fluid dynamics's stream function is entirely different from Helmholtz decomposition. They are doing complex analysis, and it holds for a totally different and bigger domain, at the cost of giving up treating viscosity.


Now I am confused on why is there a minus sign in the general definition of the Helmholtz decomposition. Is it only a matter of convention[?]

Yes.

On the Wiki page for the Stream function under "In terms of vector potential and stream surfaces"
they define a similar function:
=∇×∇
Is that a typo of the Helmholtz decomposition or are they defining something totally different?

Yes, that is something different.
